# Serviço não executa método da controller

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Esse mensagem eu recebo no browser ou postman

> "Message": "Não foram encontrados recursos HTTP que correspondam ao
>   URI de solicitação 'http://localhost:9078/api/itens/1000012105'.",
>       "MessageDetail": "Nenhuma ação foi encontrada no controlador 'Itens' que corresponda à solicitação."

O problema é que eu estou construindo um serviço onde eu passo um ID na url para que venha apenas os itens daquele orçamento. Na controller está assim:

```
public class ItensController : ApiController
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        ItensLiberacao itens = new ItensLiberacao();

        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public IEnumerable<ItensLibDTO> getItensLiberacao(int idorcamento)
        {
            return itens.getItensLib(idorcamento).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
    }
```

E aqui a classe ItensLiberacao:

```
public class ItensLiberacao
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        ItensLibDTO libDTO = new ItensLibDTO();

        public List<ItensLibDTO> getItensLib(int idorcamento)
        {
            var lista = contexto.ItensLibs
                .Where(itens => itens.IdOrcamento == idorcamento)
                .Select(item => new ItensLibDTO
                {
                    Produto = item.Produto,
                    Qtde = item.Qtde.ToString(),
                    Unitario = item.Unitario.ToString(),
                    Custo = item.Custo.ToString(),
                    CustoDiario = item.CustoDiario.ToString(),
                    UltCondicao = item.UltCondicao.ToString(),
                    Total = item.Total.ToString()
                }).ToList();

            return lista;
        }
    }
```

Como eu resolvo isso? O que está faltando mais para o service funcionar? O número: **1000012105** é o Id de um orçamento existente na base de dados.

**EDIT1**

Alterei o meu serviço para isso e continua o mesmo erro:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public HttpResponseMessage getItensLiberacao(int idorcamento)
        {
            var _itens = contexto.ItensLibs.Where(it => it.IdOrcamento == idorcamento).FirstOrDefault();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _itens);

        }
```

**EDIT2**

Se altero o método e o serviço funciona, assim:

```
public class ItensLiberacao
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        ItensLibDTO libDTO = new ItensLibDTO();

        public List<ItensLibDTO> getItensLib()
        {
            var lista = contexto.ItensLibs
                //.Where(itens => itens.IdOrcamento == idorcamento)
                .Select(item => new ItensLibDTO
                {
                    Produto = item.Produto,
                    Qtde = item.Qtde.ToString(),
                    Unitario = item.Unitario.ToString(),
                    Custo = item.Custo.ToString(),
                    CustoDiario = item.CustoDiario.ToString(),
                    UltCondicao = item.UltCondicao.ToString(),
                    Total = item.Total.ToString()
                }).ToList();

            return lista;
        }
    }
```

E o serviço:

```
public class ItensController : ApiController
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        ItensLiberacao itens = new ItensLiberacao();

        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public IEnumerable<ItensLibDTO> getItensLiberacao()
        {
            return itens.getItensLib().AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A sua rota é a default do web api?

Comment: Testa: http://localhost:9078/api/itens/getitensliberacao/1000012105 e certifique que é requisição é um GET

Comment: @GabrielColetta, continua o mesmo problema. A mesma mensagem de erro

Comment: Pessoal, o que eu observei é que não entra no método quando eu chamo na url. Uso a Rota padrão, conforme o colega @GabrielColetta perguntou. Alterei o método e mesmo assim não funciona. Estou desde às 4 e meia da manhã tentando, lendo e nada ainda, até agora.

Comment: Não sei se pode ser isso, mas quando eu alterar o método e o serviço para receber por **ID**, estou trazendo uma lista e deveria ser, acho eu, `FirstOrDefault()`. Creio que pode ser isso e vou já testar.

Comment: Qual a versão do webapi que você está usando?

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática, como eu vejo isso?

Comment: @pnet Verifica a versão do pacote do webapi no nuget. Perguntei porque tem uma forma de fazer, incluindo o seguinte atributo no método do controller: [Route( "itensliberacao/{idorcamento}" )] e passando como atributo para o controller este valor [RoutePrefix("api/itens")]

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática, pegando pelos pacotes instalados eu tenho o seguinte: **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi** Versão 5.2.3, não sei se é isso, acho que sim.

Comment: O problema é que nem entra no método na controller(serviço) e não tenho como debugar. Está totalmente errado e não sei o que é e nem tenho idéia

Comment: Muda o parâmetro de idorcamento para só id e testa.

Comment: @pnet é WebApi 2.2, testa com o que eu passei, capaz de resolver.

Comment: @ThiagoSilva, dessa forma entrou no método. Deu outro erro no campo double, mas isso é para outro post. Valeu. Poste como resposta que eu marco.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática, troquei de idorcamento para id e funcionou. Estava sem internet, por isso não comentei antes. E como eu vejo a versão do webapi?

Comment: @pnet, vi pela versão do Assembly que me passou acima, só pesquisei dai ;)

Answer (score 1):

A sua rota está configurada para que o primeiro parâmetro seja sempre chamado id.
Se você quer passar um parâmetro com outro nome você faz assim: `http://localhost:9078/api/itens?idorcamento=1000012105`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode ou trocar o parâmetro para "id" ou colocar a anotação:

```
[HttpGet("{idorcamento}")]    
public IEnumerable<ItensLibDTO> getItensLiberacao(int idorcamento){
...
}
```